# Facebook Registration Plugin not Loading

Tags: facebook

I'm using the Facebook Registration Plugin and it seems to have stopped working, but I'm not sure why.  What happens is that instead of loading the registration form, it just displays the moving bars loading icon (and never loads).  I have the necessary credentials, also in the past when my credentials were wrong, an error message would appear in the space that the form would normally show.

One thing I noticed was that when I visit the [registration's FB page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) I can see the two examples without custom fields, but I can't see the example with custom fields.  In my usage, I use custom fields.  Maybe it has something to do with using custom fields and/or firewalls?

So right now, users can't register.  Please help!  Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=myappnumberiscorrecthere&xfbml=1" %>
    <% site_url = MyApplication::Application.config.site_url %>
    <fb:registration
      fields="[
     {'name':'name'},
     {'name':'first_name'},
     {'name':'last_name'},
     {'name':'email'},
     {'name':'gender'},
     {'name':'birthday'},
     {'name':'username', 'description':'User Name', 'type':'text'},
     {'name':'postal_code', 'description':'Postal Code', 'type':'text'},
     {'name':'password'},
     {'name':'captcha'}
    ]"
      redirect-uri="https://<%= @domain + "." + site_url %>/users"
      width="530">
   </fb:registration>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the captcha field.

I'm experiencing the same problem when trying to load their documentation page with custom fields and when using the code you have provided.

By removing the captcha, it seems to work.  I presume there is a bug on Facebook's end.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the bug here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/509265599090288?browse=search_5028d48a2f1678298252951

Answer (score 0):

change it from

```
fields="[
     {'name':'name'},
     {'name':'first_name'},
     {'name':'last_name'},
     {'name':'email'},
     {'name':'gender'},
     {'name':'birthday'},
     {'name':'username', 'description':'User Name', 'type':'text'},
     {'name':'postal_code', 'description':'Postal Code', 'type':'text'},
     {'name':'password'},
     {'name':'captcha'}
    ]"
```

to

```
fields=[
     {'name':'name'},
     {'name':'first_name'},
     {'name':'last_name'},
     {'name':'email'},
     {'name':'gender'},
     {'name':'birthday'},
     {'name':'username', 'description':'User Name', 'type':'text'},
     {'name':'postal_code', 'description':'Postal Code', 'type':'text'},
     {'name':'password'},
     {'name':'captcha'}
    ]"
```